# Translate sql database schema to IndexedDB

Tags: mysql, indexeddb

I have three tables in my SQL Schema: Clients, with address and so on, orders with order details and files, which stores uploaded files. both the files table and the orders table contain foreign keys referencing the Client tables.

How would I do that in IndexedDB? IÄm new to this whole key-index-thinking and would just like to understand, how the same Thing would be done with indexedDB.

Now I know there is a shim.js file, but I'm trying to understand the concept itself.

Help and tips highly appreciated!

EDIT:

So I would really have to think about which queries I want to allow and then optimize my IndexedDB implementation for those queries, is that the main point here? Basically, I want to to store a customer once and then many orders for that customer and then be able to upload small files (preferably pdfs) for that customer, not even necessarily for each order (although if that's easy to implement, I may do it)... I see every customer as a separate entity, I wont have things like "give me all customers who ordered xy" - I only need to have each customer once and then store all the orders for the customer and all the files. I wanto be able to go: Search for customer with the name of XY - which then gives me a list of all orders and their dates and a list of the files uploaded for that customer (maybe associated to the order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a bit too broad to answer correctly. Nevertheless, the major concept to learn when transitioning from SQL to No-SQL (indexedDB) is the concept of object stores. Most SQL databases are relational and perform much of the work of optimizing queries for you. indexedDB does not. So the concepts of normalization and denormalization work a bit differently. The focal point is to explicitly plan your own queries. Unlike the design of an app/system that allows simple ad-hoc SQL queries that are designed at a later point in time, and possibly even easily added/changed at a later time, you really need to do a lot of the planning up front for indexedDB.

So it is not quite safe to say that the transition is simply a matter of creating three object stores to correspond to your three relational tables. For one, there is no concept of joining in indexedDB so you cannot join on foreign keys.

It is not clear from your question but your 3 tables are clients, orders, and files. I will go out on a limb here and make some guesses.  I would bet you could use a single object store, clients. Then, for each client object, store the normal client properties, store an orders array property, and store a files array property. In the orders array, store order objects.

If your files are binary, this won't work, you will need to use blobs, and may even encounter issues with blob support in various browser indexedDB implementations (Chrome sort of supports it, it is unclear from version to version).

This assumes your typical query plan is that you need to do something like list the orders for a client, and that is the most frequently used type of query.

If you needed to do something across orders, independent of which client an order belongs to, this would not work so well and you would have to iterate over the entire store.

If the clients-orders relation is many to many, then this also would not work so well, because of the need to store the order info redundantly per client. However, one note here, is that this redundant storage is quite common in NoSQL-style databases like indexedDB. The goal is not to perfectly model the data, but to store the data in such a way that it your most frequently occurring queries complete quickly (while still maintaining correctness).

Edit:

Based on your edit, I would suggest a simple prototype that uses three object stores.  In your client view page where you display client details, simply run three separate queries.

1. Get the one entity from the client object store based on client id.
2. Open a cursor over the orders and get all orders for the client. In the orders store, use a client-id property. Create an index on this client-id property. Open the cursor over the index for a specific client id.
3. Open a cursor over the files store using a similar tactic as #2.

In your bizlogic layer, enforce your data constraints. For example, when deleting a client, first delete all the files from the files store, then delete all the orders from the orders store, and then delete the single client entity from the client store.

What I am suggesting is to not overthink it. It is not that complicated. So far you have not described something that sounds like it will have performance issues so there is no need for something more elegant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer!! My answer was too long for a comment, so I edited the question.

Comment: Brilliant, thanx man! I'll try to work that into my code. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

I will go with Josh answer but if you are still finding it hard to use indexeddb and want to continue using sql. You can use sqlweb - It  will let you do operation inside indexeddb by using sql query.

e.g -

```
var connection = new JsStore.Instance('jsstore worker path');
connection.runSql("select * from Customers").then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Here is the link - http://jsstore.net/tutorial/sqlweb/